# How do I copy data from one table to another table on another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL that on a production database finds about 3000 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM [CONTOSO].[BATID] (NOLOCK)
WHERE COMPANYNO = 1
AND MEASURINGPOINT = '592-98901_NPT'
AND TIMESERIESNO = 1
AND DATE_TIME >= '2013-01-31 23:00:00'
AND DATE_TIME <= '2013-02-28 22:59:00'
ORDER BY DATE_TIME
```

Is there some way that I can convert the output into some kind of big 'INSERT INTO....'-sql that would insert this data into the same table. Then I would easily be able to copy the sql into the other SQL Server Management Studio-window and execute it.

Comment: By far the easiest, if you have access (and are allowed) to do so, is to link the two servers and then just use an ordinary insert into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your servers are not connected, you can use the [SSMS import/ export wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx). This export creates a data file that you can then import at the remote server.

Comment: Thank you. For now this is what I was looking for. I did a little formatting in Notepad++ to convert each line into an 'INSERT INTO...' line.

Comment: Not to be a butt, but if you wrote "code that writes code", then in the future you can by-pass the manual steps you did in notepad++.  I guess it depends if this is a one-time or something you gotta do over and over.  Its easier to tweak "code that writes code" IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO TableName (collName1, colName2,...)
SELECT * -- this should match to the names of column define in the INSERT clause
FROM [CONTOSO].[BATID] (NOLOCK)
WHERE COMPANYNO = 1
AND MEASURINGPOINT = '592-98901_NPT'
AND TIMESERIESNO = 1
AND DATE_TIME >= '2013-01-31 23:00:00'
AND DATE_TIME <= '2013-02-28 22:59:00'
```

Comment: Not sure that would work - this assumes that you can see the access the other server when running the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If create table as select is available in your version of SQL then you can use this:

```
Create table tab_name AS
 SELECT... your query...
```

Answer (score 0):

SSMS Tools Pack has a great Generate Insert Statements function:
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/
It allows you to easily enter the where clause to get just the data you want to export.
This used to be totally free but now requires a small fee if using with SSMS 2012+

If you have more money and need to do this kind of thing a lot, then Red Gate's SQL Data Compare is a great tool:
https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Answer (score 0):

You can write code that creates code.

I 've done it for the "MembershipProvider" database here:
http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2007/11/29/membershipprovider-helper-to-transfer-data/

You can modify to fit your needs.

Watch the double and single quotes, they'll throw a monkey wrench in the plans.

Here is a preview of the bigger code example:

Note, it creates code that can be run on the second sql server.

```
    select 
    'INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Applications ( ApplicationName,LoweredApplicationName,ApplicationId,[Description] ) values ('  as [--Comment], 
    char(39) + t1.ApplicationName + char(39) ,  ',' , 
    char(39) + t1.LoweredApplicationName + char(39) ,  ',' , 
    char(39) + convert(varchar(38)  , t1.ApplicationId ) + char(39) ,  ',' , 
    char(39) + t1.Description + char(39) 
    , ')'
     FROM
        dbo.aspnet_Applications t1
```

Here is a Northwind example that handles single quotes in the CompanyName and Address columns, and has a "where not exists" check on the PrimaryKey.  Note, this table did not have any ints/numbers, but simply removing the single quotes will work.  If you want to check for null values, that's a simple case statement as seen in the Fax column.

```
Select 'INSERT INTO dbo.Customers ( CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,[Address],City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax ) '   as [--Comment], 
'SELECT ' , 
char(39) + t1.CustomerID + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + REPLACE(t1.CompanyName , char(39) , char(39) + '+' + 'char(39)' + '+' +  char(39) ) + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.ContactName + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.ContactTitle + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + REPLACE(t1.[Address] , char(39) , char(39) + '+' + 'char(39)' + '+' +  char(39) ) + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.City + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.Region + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.PostalCode + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.Country + char(39) ,  ',' , 
char(39) + t1.Phone + char(39) ,  ',' , 
Fax = case
    when t1.Fax is null then 'null'
    else char(39) + t1.[Fax] + char(39) 
    end
, ' Where not exists (select null from dbo.Customers innerC where innerC.CustomerID = ' + char(39) + t1.CustomerID + char(39) + ')'
 FROM
dbo.Customers t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and then copy data from one table to another table on Linked Server.

```
sp_addlinkedserver  
  @server= N'NameofLinkedServer',
  @srvproduct= N'',
  @provider= N'SQLNCLI',
  @datasrc= N'YourRemoteServer';

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
  @rmtsrvname = 'NameofLinkedServer' ,
  @useself = 'FALSE' ,
  @locallogin = 'local_login' ,
  @rmtuser = 'remote_login' ,
  @rmtpassword = 'remote_password'
```

After creating [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) execute this INSERT statement

```
INSERT [NameofLinkedServer].[your_databaseName].[CONTOSO].[BATID](Column1, Column2, ...)
SELECT (Column1, Column2, ...)
FROM [CONTOSO].[BATID] (NOLOCK)
WHERE COMPANYNO = 1
AND MEASURINGPOINT = '592-98901_NPT'
AND TIMESERIESNO = 1
AND DATE_TIME >= '2013-01-31 23:00:00'
AND DATE_TIME <= '2013-02-28 22:59:00'
ORDER BY DATE_TIME
```

For details, see the [**MSDN docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)